# Creating .txt output with string and numbers in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, output

I'm new to matlab.
I have multiple `.txt` files with up to 1000 each with a content as the following:

> 09.10.2015,08:17:02,51683,8,3286,78,6,7,0,13

I'm trying to merge all `.txt` files together to create one big `.txt` file that I can use for further analysis.
The `.txt` files have the same number of columns but different number of lines.
I don't have difficulties merging the files if there are the numbers only but the date and time causes difficulties. 
Really would appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: What did you attempt so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for Matlab, as you will be reading data (with format) writing data (creating new file). Which is inefficient and could blow-up your memory if you have BIG BIG data.

This is a job for Bash - Unix, something like:

```
cat *.txt > bigFile.txt
```

Or in Windows :

```
cat *.txt >> bigFile.txt
```

Or

```
copy /b *.txt bigFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read all files, store them somehow (in a matrix, in a cell), whatever suits you better.

Use fopen, fread, fid, or even simpler - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html

Once you have your information totally organized, just use this function - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html